# When to add dbcontext service to startup?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dbcontext

I have 2 different "design pattern" projects in Solution:
1-ChainOfResponsibiltyDesignPattern and 2-RepositoryDesignPattern :

[image]

Context of ChainOfResponsibiltyDesignPattern
[image]

startup of ChainOfResponsibiltyDesignPattern
[image]

context of RepositoryDesignPattern
[image]

start of RepositoryDesignPattern
[image]

I have 2 different "design pattern" projects in Solution:
1-ChainOfResponsibiltyDesignPattern,
2-RepositoryDesignPattern.
Both of them have the same framework and 5.0.
Although the dbcontext class of both is the same, "services.AddDbContext(); is not required in the startup configuration file for ChainOfResponsibiltyDesignPattern, while it is required for RepositoryDesignPattern.

Why does this happen even though the dbcontext class is the same for both of them?
In what cases do we have to wait for the dbcontext service in the configuration?

Thanks.

Comment: I am really struggling to understand your question. I think this might stem from the fact you don't understand how DI works. What do you mean by `AddDbContext is not required"? Also "dbcontext class is the same for both of them" makes no sense?

Comment: In the startup file of the ChainOfResponsibiltyDesignPattern project "services.AddDbContext<Context>();" I can run the project when I don't add "services.AddDbContext<Context>();" I am not asked to add it.
But
In the startup file of the RepositoryDesignPattern project "services.AddDbContext<Context>();" I can't run the project when I don't add "services.AddDbContext<Context>();" I am asked to add.
Why is this the case? I wanted to ask this.

Comment: Could you post some beginning part of code of defaultcontroller.cs and homecontroller.cs in ChainOfResponsibiltyDesignPattern

Comment: Sure.  I am using "DefaultController"..
[enter image description here] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XMrJ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IaOq.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have the `Context` class but doesn't make a dependency injection to use in project "ChainOfResponsibiltyDesignPattern".
When you want to make a instance of a "class"(public class ...)  by "denpendency injection" way , you will need to register the class to service.

It means when there's some code like below (using dependency injection) in your project:

```
    public class xxxxxx 
    {
        private readonly Context context;

        public xxxxxx(Context context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }
    }
```

You will need to register the `Context` like `builder.Services.AddSingleton<Context>();` But as `Context` is a special database class, you could register to use `builder.Services.AddDbContext<Context>();`

Reference:https://stackify.com/net-core-dependency-injection/

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you wrote because I'm at the beginner level. Thank you very much for your time.
So, if I use something like the following, I need to add it to the service, right?
 





`public class xxxxxx
     {
         private readonly Context context;

         public xxxxxx(Context context)
         {
             this.context = context;
         }
     }`

Comment: @Karayeniceri Yes, that's right.

Comment: @Karayeniceri to better understanding these, you may need to study from "Register interface service" --> "Register class to service directly"  --> "efcore database context service register"

Comment: thank you. 
I can't understand whether I will need to add service for each class (Context context etc.) that is created when I define a "constructor".
I'm thinking about this.

Comment: @Karayeniceri  Well, you can also create a instance directly by `var context=new Context()` without constructor, then you needn't add class to service.    But when you create instance by constructor, you are using dependency injection way. In this way all the instance stays in the "service container". And the service container controls the instance lifecycles such as "transient,scoped,singleton" for different usage.

Comment: @Quian Fu Thank you very much for your explanations. I think it's like you said, but if I encounter a different situation, I will share it :)